# Web-scraping error in R

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I'm learning how to do web-scraping in R and thought I'd try things out by using a page with a built in table. My ultimate goal is to have dataframe with four variables (Name, Party, Constituency, Link to individual webpage).

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)

url <- "http://www.parliament.uk/mps-lords-and-offices/mps/?sort=0"

constituency <- read_html(url)
print(constituency)

constituency_red <- constituency %>% html_nodes('td') %>% html_text()
constituency_red <- paste0(url, constituency_red)
constituency_red <- unique(constituency_red)
constituency_red
```

The output I get after completing these steps looks like I'm going in the right direction. However, as you can see when scrolling to the right it's still a bit of a mess. Any ideas on what I can do to clean this up?

```
[974] "http://www.parliament.uk/mps-lords-and-offices/mps/?sort=0\r\n                                Poulter, Dr\r\n                                (Conservative)\r\n                            "                               
[975] "http://www.parliament.uk/mps-lords-and-offices/mps/?sort=0Central Suffolk and North Ipswich"                                                                                                                               
[976] "http://www.parliament.uk/mps-lords-and-offices/mps/?sort=0\r\n                                Pound, Stephen\r\n                                (Labour)\r\n                            "                                  
[977] "http://www.parliament.uk/mps-lords-and-offices/mps/?sort=0Ealing North"
```

After this I tried a second approach. The following code appears to give me a clean list of all the hyperlinks. So I'm wondering if this might be a potential work around?

```
constituency_links <- constituency %>% html_nodes("tr") %>% html_nodes('td') %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")
constituency_links <- paste0(url, constituency_links)
constituency_links <- unique(constituency_links)
constituency_links
```

My third and final try was to use the following code:

```
all_constituency <- lapply(constituency_links, function(x) read_html(x))
all_constituency
```

When I run this things slow down A LOT and then I start getting `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 400.` So I tried running it as a loop instead.

```
for(i in constituency_links){
all_constituency[[i]] <- read_html(i) 
}
```

I get the same error messages with this approach. Any suggestions on how to pull and clean this information would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringi)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

pg <- read_html("http://www.parliament.uk/mps-lords-and-offices/mps/?sort=0")
td_1 <- html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//td[contains(@id,'ctl00_ctl00_FormContent_SiteSpecificPlaceholder_PageContent_rptMembers_ctl')]")

data_frame(mp_name=html_text(html_nodes(td_1, "a")),
           href=html_attr(html_nodes(td_1, "a"), "href"),
           party=map_chr(stri_match_all_regex(html_text(td_1), "\\((.*)\\)"), 2),
           constituency=html_text(html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//tr/td[2]"))) -> df

glimpse(df)
## Observations: 649
## Variables: 4
## $ mp_name      <chr> "Abbott, Ms Diane", "Abrahams, Debbie", "Adams, N...
## $ href         <chr> "http://www.parliament.uk/biographies/commons/ms-...
## $ party        <chr> "Labour", "Labour", "Conservative", "Conservative...
## $ constituency <chr> "Hackney North and Stoke Newington", "Oldham East...
```

Answer (score 1):

We can start by obtaining text strings with MP names, party, and constituency:

```
text <- constituency %>% html_nodes('table') %>% html_nodes('tr') %>% html_text()
head(text, 3)
# [1] "Surname, First name\r\n                            Constituency\r\n\t\r\n                        "                                                                              
# [2] "A\r\n                            back to top\r\n                        "                                                                                                       
# [3] "\r\n                                Abbott, Ms Diane\r\n                                (Labour)\r\n                            \r\n\t\tHackney North and Stoke Newington\r\n\t"
```

We can iterate through `text`, parse each element and split up the string into the fields we want (name, party, constituency):

```
dd <- lapply(text, function(x) {
  out <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\r\n"))[c(2, 3, 5)]                # Use "\r\n" to split the strings
  as.vector(sapply(out, function(x) sub("(\\t)+|\\s+", "", x))) # Remove spaces and the "\t"
})
# [[1]]
# [1] "Constituency" ""             NA            

# [[2]]
# [1] "back to top" ""            NA           

# [[3]]
# [1] "Abbott, Ms Diane"                  "(Labour)"                         
# [3] "Hackney North and Stoke Newington"
```

Now, make `dd` into a dataframe, filtering out irrelevant rows (where `party` is blank):

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(dd), nc = 3, byrow = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df) <- c("name", "party", "con")
df$party <- sub("\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", df$party)   # Remove parentheses
df <- df[df$party != "", ]                       # Remove rows where party is blank
head(df, 3)
#               name        party                               con
# 3 Abbott, Ms Diane       Labour Hackney North and Stoke Newington
# 4 Abrahams, Debbie       Labour       Oldham East and Saddleworth
# 5     Adams, Nigel Conservative                  Selby and Ainsty
```

We can now deal with the links. When we inspect the links, those that are relevant to the MPs have the word "biographies" in them, so we use that to filter the list:

```
links <- constituency %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")
links <- links[grepl("biographies", links)]
head(links, 3)
# [1] "http://www.parliament.uk/biographies/commons/ms-diane-abbott/172" 
# [2] "http://www.parliament.uk/biographies/commons/debbie-abrahams/4212"
# [3] "http://www.parliament.uk/biographies/commons/nigel-adams/4057"
```

And complete our dataframe by adding the links:

```
df$links <- links
str(head(df, 3))
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ name : chr  "Abbott, Ms Diane" "Abrahams, Debbie" "Adams, Nigel"
#  $ party: chr  "Labour" "Labour" "Conservative"
#  $ con  : chr  "Hackney North and Stoke Newington" "Oldham East and Saddleworth" "Selby and Ainsty"
#  $ links: chr  "http://www.parliament.uk/biographies/commons/ms-diane-abbott/172" "http://www.parliament.uk/biographies/commons/debbie-abrahams/4212" "http://www.parliament.uk/biographies/commons/nigel-adams/4057"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the step by step. It helped a lot understanding what was going on with each part.